# Related to Euclidean and unitary vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional Euclidean or unitary $K$-vector space. Show or refute the following statements:

(i) $(f + g)^{*} = f^{*} + g^{*}$ for all $f, g ∈ \operatorname{End}(V)$

(ii) $(λf)^{*}$ = $λf^{*}$ for all $ f ∈ \operatorname{End}(V)$ and $λ ∈ K$

(iii) $(f ◦ g)^{*}$ = $f^{*}$ $◦$ $g^{*}$ for all $f, g ∈ \operatorname{End}(V)$

(iv) $f^{-1}$$(U^{⊥})$ = $f^{*}(U)^{⊥}$ for all $f ∈ \operatorname{End}(V)$ and all subspaces $U ⊆ V$

(v) $\operatorname{rk}(f)$ = $\operatorname{rk}(f^{*})$ for all $f ∈ \operatorname{End}(V)$

What are the properties related to the $^{*}$, $◦$, and $^{⊥}$ and $\operatorname{End}(V)$ that may help show or refute the statements?

Extra notes:

$^{*}$ $=$  Hermitian adjoint

$^{⊥}$ $=$ orthogonal complement

$End(V)$ = endomorphism of the unitary space V

unitary space = complex inner product space

Comment: What is $^*$ in this case? I was thinking it was the adjoint, but that would make property (iii) false.

Comment: @TheoBendit That is precisely the problem! Prove or refute. By the way, to the post owner: you need to provide the definition of $(-)^*$, $(-)^\perp$ and unitary space, since they are not universal terms.

Comment: @azif00 Thank you for your comment. I added some comments to clarify the definitions of the terms and operations.